# Как сделать текст в <input>

Tags: html, css, sublime-text-3, layout

Необходимо сделать так
[image]

1. **Для чего `transform:translateX`**
2. **Как задать позицию `absolute` относительно родитея**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код который касаеться только формы (если кидать весь нет смысла т.к у всех разные сайты просто подставишь то что функционирует тут и всё)

**html**

```
<div class="offset-lg-3 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form">
        <p class="formTitle">
            Для рассчёта точной стоимости<br>
            закажите <strong>выезд замерщика</strong>
        </p>

        <!-- also I added div "inputs" -->
        <div class="inputs">
            <!-- <label class="formName" for="name">Ваше имя</label> -->
            <label class="inputText" for="name">Ваше имя</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control bg-dark" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="">
            <!-- <label class="formPhone" for="phone">Ваш телефон</label> -->
            <label class="inputText" for="phone">Ваш телефон</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control bg-dark" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <a class="button" href="#">Узнать стоимость</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
  background-color: #202020;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
}
.form {
  background-color: #212529;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.form input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form .inputText {
  color: white;
  background-color: #202020;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-55%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-55%);
  padding: 0 3%;
}
.formTitle {
  display: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**CSS** (less)

```css
body {
    background-color: #202020;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    color:white;
}

 .form {
    background-color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:30px 20px;
    position:relative;
    input {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    // .formName {
    //     position: absolute;
    //     background-color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
    //     left:8rem;
    //     top:5rem;
    //     padding: 0 0.5rem;
    // }
    //     .formPhone {
    //     position: absolute;
    //     background-color:rgb(33, 37, 41);
    //     left:7.5rem;
    //     top:8.7rem;
    //     padding: 0 0.5rem;
    // }

    .inputText {
        color:white; //sample
        background-color: #202020; //sample
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        left:50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-55%);
        padding:0 3%;
    }
}

.formTitle {
    display:inherit;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Пояснение как это делалось**
Задал родителю `inputs` в котором лежат `input` `position:relative` после задаю потомкам/дочерним классам `label` `position:absolute` для того чтобы они не были привязаны к другим элемнтам при этом были в рамках родителя (т.е было ограничение в этой форме) (т.е в пределах этой формы) дальше просто `left:50%` и при помощи `transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-55%);` подогнал

`transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-55%);` нужно писать в одну строку
Эта команда (метод) нужен чтобы при `left:50%` элемент выравнивался по его центру а не по левому верхнему краю

Иначе говоря чтобы было вот так:
[image: Привязка к центру]

Вместо так:
[image: Привязка к левому верхнему краю]